# Lua: attempt to index field (a nil value)

Tags: lua, torch

I'm trying to print out the values in the batch tensor in Test:run() from this code: https://github.com/zhangxiangxiao/Crepe/blob/master/train/test.lua

I tried the following at the start of the for loop:

```
print(ffi.string(torch.data(self.batch.content:narrow(1, self.batch[1][1][1], 1))))
```

but I get the following error:

```
qlua: ./test.lua:63: attempt to index field 'content' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function '__index'   
        ./test.lua:63: in function 'run'
        main.lua:145: in function 'run'
        main.lua:42: in function 'main'
        main.lua:316:in main chunk
```

Batch's dimensions are 50x1014x69 and is type userdata, so I'm not sure why indexing 1,1,1 would be nil...

Comment: Looks like `self.batch` don't have `content` field.

Comment: the error says that `self.batch.content == nil` and because you can't do `(nil):narrow(...)` the error appears.